# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_multiarray)

Tags: python, numpy

Im using python3.5 64 bits and try to import numpy. The following errors pop up

```
C:\Users\azhang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.exe C:/Users/azhang/PycharmProjects/trial/1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\azhang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_multiarray)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/azhang/PycharmProjects/trial/1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\azhang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\azhang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\azhang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\azhang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\azhang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

Original error was:

```
dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_multiarray)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

what is the issue here? how do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried reinstall numpy?

Comment: @ding I uninstalled numpy use the `pip uninstall numpy` but its still the same error after I reinstall it.